# Roboelectric background thread synchronization

Tags: android, multithreading, unit-testing, callback, robolectric

```
    @Test
public void testShows() throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final TestCallback<ArrayList<CompleteShow>> call = new TestCallback<ArrayList<CompleteShow>>();
    webService.showsListByCategory("0", call);


    await().until(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return call.isDone;
        }
    });

    assertNotNull(call.t);
```

}

I have been trying to test a web service implmented using retrofit library using roboelectric. But I just cant get a callback. This seems to be a simple problem and I have tried using CountdownLatch as well awaitility but no success.